# Django - For loop for two variables passed in a dictionary

Tags: mysql, django, dictionary, for-loop

In my `view.py` file I have two queries, each assigned a variable name. Query 1 collects all of the reviews in the reviews table. Query 2 calculates the average rating for each review from the reviews table. Two queries, one table.

I've placed `Query 1` (named `reviews`) and `Query 2` (named `ratings`) inside of a dictionary named `context` to be passed to my html file.

My goal is to show each review and that review's rating. However I'm having trouble displaying it properly with my current approach. Here's my html file:

```
{% extends "reviews/layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for review in reviews %}
      {% for rating in ratings %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ review.author.profile.image.url }}">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <h4 class="mr-2">{{ review.company }} {{ rating.rate }}</h4>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ review.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            </div>
            <h5><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'review-detail' review.id %}">{{ review.title }}</a></h5>
            <p class="article-content">{{ review.content }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I have a `for` loop within a `for` loop. As expected, the result is for each review is being display over and over again for each average. For example, I have 7 reviews with 7 ratings. The results are looking like this: (NOTE: I placed the results in code tags so they would be seen easier.)

```
Review 1, rating for review 1
Review 1, rating for review 2
Review 1, rating for review 3
Review 1, rating for review 4
Review 1, rating for review 5
Review 1, rating for review 6
Review 1, rating for review 7

Review 2, rating for review 1
Review 2, rating for review 2
....
Review 2, rating for review 7
```

Instead, my goal is to see:

```
Review 1, rating for review 1
Review 2, rating for review 2
Review 3, rating for review 3
Review 4, rating for review 4
...
```

My `view.py` file:

```
def reviews(request):
    reviews = Review.objects.all()

    ratings = Review.objects.filter(id__in=[review.id for review in reviews]).annotate(rate=(F('value1')+F('value2')+F('value3')+F('value4'))/4)

    context = {
        'reviews': reviews,
        'ratings': ratings
    }
    return render(request, 'reviews/reviews.html', context)
```

I've read other situations using `zip()`, but I don't think applies to my case?

I know this is a rookie challenge, but I'm new to Django and I'm learning. All advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might just be personal prefererence but I like to combine related context fields.
If I understood your code correctly you want all ratings for a review, and this can be acheived by editing the view.

```
def someview(request):
  reviews = Review.objects.all()
  review_list = []
  for review in reviews:
     ratings = Rating.objects.filter(review=review)
     ratings_list = []
     for rating in ratings:
        ratings_list.append({
             'rating_value':rating.value
        })
     review_list.append({
          'id':review.pk
          'ratings':ratings_list,
     })
  context = {'reviews':review_list}
```

Then in your html you can do for example:

```
{% for review in reviews %}
      {% for rating in review.ratings %}
      Review {{review.id}}, rating is {{rating.value}}
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I misread your answer earlier. It's working perfectly now. Thank you so much!!